# propagate status checkboxes in a tree using GAS

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, treeview

I have a tree in a scrollPanel in a stackPanel The tree contains over 300 treeitems, each having a checkbox.
Depending on the status of a userproperty, I want to propagate the status of the checkbox clicked to its sub treeitems.
I have a method for finding the ids of each checkbox of each (sub)treeitem. The method has been used for building the tree as well.

Each checkbox has (the same) onValueChangeHandler

```
function onChangeStatusChkTreeItem(e)
{ // Set all checkboxes of subtreeitems TRUE or FALSE in case 'propagate' will be true
     var app = UiApp.createApplication();
     var chkSource = e.parameter.source;
     var triSource = chkSource.replace(chkPrefix, triPrefix); // chkPrefix and triPrefix are global variables
     var status = (e.parameter.button == 1); // New status of the checkbox
     var propagate = userProperties.getProperty('propagateToSubFofolders');
     propagate = ((propagate == true) || (propagate == 'true'));
     if (propagate == false)
     { // Just this checkbox
        userProperties.setProperty(triSource, status);
        app.getElementById(chkSource).setValue(status, true); // (`false` makes no difference) 
     }
     else
     { // Include subtree as well
        var props = userProperties.getProperties();
        var propsChanged = {};
        var changes = 0; 
        updateSubTree_(triSource, chkSource);
        if (changes > 0) userProperties.setProperties(propsChanged);
     }

     function updateTree_(treeItemId, chkTreeItemId)
     { // Internal function : Set all subtreeitems as well
        if (props[treeItemId] !=  status)
        { // Update needed
           changes++;
           propsChanged[treeItemId] = status;
           var chk = app.getElementById(chkTreeItemId);
           chk.setValue(status, false);  .. chk.setValue(status, true) maakt geen verschil

           // loop through the children of treeItemId (pseudo code --> tested)
           for each child
           {
              newTriId --> created
              newChkId --> created based on newTriId
              updateTree_(newTriId, newChkId);
           }
        }
     }
}
```

But the checkboxes in the tree will NOT be updated.

So my question is : what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something I'm pretty sure an application created using UiApp is unaware of its own state until you call `return app;`.

Any changes your code makes will not be reflected until this happens, include it at the end of your onValueChangeHandler()